# Emacs: how do I set a major-mode stored in a variable?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Suppose I have a variable newName which is bearing some mode name, e.g. `"python-mode"`. How do I make current buffer of the mode specified by newName?

```
(progn
  (let (newName)
    (setq newName "python-mode")
    (newName) ;; doesn't work! It doesn't set current buffer's mode to be a python mode.
  )
)
```

This also doesn't work:

```
(set-variable 'major-mode "python-mode")
```

This question is fundamental - since it is equal to "is it really possible to treat data as code in lisp?"

**Edit**

@phils

Your solution doesn't work for me. I copy a buffer - and I want the new one to have the same mode as the old one. So I store the mode of the original buffer in the variable. Then try to apply Your solution. It gives error (it's the essence - I omit here the buffer-copying stuff):

```
(let (sameMode)
  (setq sameMode major-mode)
  (funcall (intern sameMode))
)
```

sameMode stores here mode in the form of "python-mode" (example for python-mode).

Comment: phils has the answer for you, but as an aside, whatever would make you think you could use strings as functions, especially without `funcall`? I really recommend reading the documentation for things like this, since it's included with emacs and would have easily answered this question. Guessing how a language works without trying to understand it first is unlikely to give you much success!

Comment: Adobe: In Lisp, there is a difference of a variable has a string value or an atom value. The function `intern` converts a string to an atom. In Emacs, the value of `major-mode` is an atom an thus you should not use `intern`. Btw. This is exactly as @phils specified in his second example in his answer.

Comment: @ Lindydancer: You do make things clear!

Comment: I just got around to checking the elisp definition of an atom (as I would have called it a symbol myself), and I think that's incorrect terminology. `intern` returns a symbol. An atom is any object which is not a cons cell, and therefore a string *is* an atom (which you can confirm with the `(atom)` predicate function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(let ((mode "python-mode"))
  (funcall (intern mode)))
```

or

```
(let ((mode 'python-mode))
  (funcall mode))
```

Comment: The second is not good for me - for I don't know ahead which mode will be in a variable - so I have my mode in the form `"python-mode"` (that's just an example - could be some other mode instead). Your first answer solves the problem - thank You so much. So all in all it's true - lisp could treat data as code!

Comment: I've updated the question - Your solution doesn't work for me. Can You please improve it?

Comment: Nevermind - Lindydancer explained it for me. You were 100% right and made kind of an ideal answer!